# Why does the existence of events with probability $p^n, q^n$ contradict with the given statement?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In the book of Shiryaev, *Probability*, it is given on page 46 that

\begin{array}{l}{\text { Let us put } S_{0}(\omega) \equiv 0 \text { and }} \\ {\qquad S_{k}=\xi_{1}+\cdots+\xi_{k}, \quad k=1, \ldots, n} \\ {\text { As we found above, } E S_{n}=n p \text { and consequently }} \\ {\qquad E \frac{S_{n}}{n}=p \text { . }} \\ {\text { In other words, the mean value of the frequency of "success", i.e. $S_n/n$, coincides with the probability p of success. } } \\ {\text { Hence we are led to ask how much the frequency $S_n/n$ of success differs from its probability p. }} \\ {\text { We first note that we cannot expect that for large $p$ }} \\ {\text { and for sufficiently large } n \text { , the deviation of } S_{n}/n \text { from } p \text { is less than } \varepsilon \text { for all }} \\ {\text { $\omega$, i.e. that }}\end{array}
\begin{array}{l}{\qquad\left|\frac{s_{n}(\omega)}{n}-p\right| \leq \varepsilon, \quad \omega \in \Omega\qquad (2)} \\ {\text { In fact, when } 0<p<1} \\ {\qquad \begin{aligned} P\left\{\frac{S_{n}}{n}=1\right\} &=P\left\{\xi_{1}=1, \ldots, \xi_{n}=1\right\}=p^{n} \\ P\left\{\frac{S_{n}}{n}=0\right\} &=P\left\{\xi_{1}=0, \ldots, \xi_{n}=0\right\}=q^{n} \end{aligned}} \\ {\text { whence it follows that }(2) \text { is not satisfied for suficiently small } \varepsilon>0}\end{array}

However, I cannot understand how the existence of those two events contradicts with the statement given. I mean since $0 < p,q < 1$, $p^n, q^n$ can be made small as much as we want for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: What does $(2)$ refer to in the last line of the proof?

Comment: I'm confused by the claim that the mean value of the frequence of success *differs* from $p$ when just one line before it is claimed that it *does* equal $p$. Are you sure you copied everything correctly?

Comment: @Milten see my edit please

Comment: @Vincent Sorry, OCR app was somehow mixed that part. See my last edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is the thing: while it is true (and somewhat aligned with intuition) that the probability of finding an outcome $\omega$ for which $|S_n(\omega)/n - p| < \epsilon$ converges to $1$ as $n$ approaches infinity (this is not in the quote, this is just the strong law of large numbers) the quote warns us that it is *never* true (no matter how large $n$) that we'll have $|S_n(\omega)/n - p| < \epsilon$ for *all* $\omega$. In other words: no matter how big your sample size or how many times you repeat your experiment: there will always be (excessively unlikely) outcomes $\omega$ for which $S_n(\omega)/n$ differes from its expectation $p$ by more than $\epsilon$.

To prove this point the book just gives an example of such an $\omega$: the event where $S_n = 0$. Since the value of $p$ is fixed we have in this case that $|S_n(\omega)/n - p| = p$  is independent of $n$ and by choosing $\epsilon < p$ we get our desired example of an event for which $|S_n(\omega)/n - p| > \epsilon$. Now what remains to be shown is that this event has positive probability, i.e. can actually happen. This is what the computation does.

However, as a free bonus, we also see from the same computation that this positive probability is really small, and becomes smaller and smaller with increasing $n$. (You also mention this in the last line of the post.) This paves the way for the next 'natural' question: could it be the case that the probability of finding *any* outcome $\omega$ such that $|S_n(\omega)/n - p| > \epsilon$ also becomes smaller and smaller with $n$?

The answer to this is of course yes (the famous Strong Law of Large Numbers) and I expect that this is what the book will talk about next. (But I don't have the book here.)